# MySQL - how to change default autocommit for one specific database?

Tags: mysql, transactions, commit

I have a MySQL 5.5.54 database with `autocommit` off:

**my.cnf**

```
...
[mysqld]
autocommit = 0
...
```

I want to include a new database for a software I'm testing but this software requires auto commit on. I don't have access to the software's code.

Is there anything I could do in MySQL to set `autocommit` on only for one database?

Thanks

Comment: You can make use of transaction to commit your statements.

Comment: @RohitKumar Thanks but I don't have access to this software code.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this to change default autocommit

```
SET autocommit = 1;
```

The value may like :
1 = ON and
0= OFF

Answer (score 0):

Autocommit is an attribute of a session, not a database.

Given that you can make queries against multiple databases during a session or during a transaction, it's not clear what it would mean to change autocommit for a given database.

You can also change the global default autocommit, but not per database.

---

Re followup question from @qxlab:

"Thanks, so does that mean that either the software configures its session autocommit value, or I change the global default value?"

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html which includes this statement:

> With `START TRANSACTION`, autocommit remains disabled until you end the transaction with `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. The autocommit mode then reverts to its previous state.

So you don't need to change the autocommit value if you want to do a transaction comprised of multiple actions. Just start the transaction.

Comment: Thanks, so does that mean that either the software configures its session autocommit value, or I change the global default value?